# Show that if a transitive subgroup $G\subset S_n$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ contains a n-1 cycle and transposition,then $G=S_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

Show that if a transitive subgroup $G\subset S_n$ of the symmetric group $S_n$ contains a n-1 cycle and transposition,then $G=S_n$.

Firstly, without loss of the genralization, we can assume the n-1 cycle is $(2,   3,4,....,n-1)$, and the transposition is (1,2), but how can we prove that (1,2) and (2,3,...,n-1) generates $S_n$

Comment: By conjugating the first generator by the second, the subgroup generated contains $(1,k)$ for all $k$.

Comment: you are right! Thanks!